# IGDB V4 Post Request in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, curl, post

If you go to : https://reqbin.com/curl
and post and send this curl command

```
curl 'https://api.igdb.com/v4/games/' \
-d 'fields name, url, cover;where id = 296;' \
-H 'Client-ID: removed' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer removed' \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

it works.

so I'm trying to do this in vb.net

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim reader As StreamReader

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Try

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://api.igdb.com/v4/games/"), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Headers.Add("Client-ID: removed")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer removed")
    request.Headers.Add("fields: name, url, where id = 296")


    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim rawresp As String
    rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

    rt.Text = (rawresp)


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

in IGDB api V3 there is no problem with the http post with this code..
but in V4 id does not work.

problem is in this line

```
request.Headers.Add("fields: name, url, where id = 296")
```

I have no idea how to put that "where id = 296" in the header in the post request :(
Im struggling with this for days. really appreciate if someone can help

Comment: In curl, `-d` is the data to send, so you need to send that string, `fields: name, url, where id = 296"` as data, setting `HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"` beforehand. Use a StreamWriter to write the data to the request stream (`request.GetRequestStream()`).  Remove `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True`: your code is not handling that.

Comment: Just to reiterate what @Jimi said: `fields` isn't being sent as a header in the example you are trying to follow.

Comment: @Jimi thank you.. i will try to do that..

Comment: @MichaelWelch yes. thank you.. i will try that

Comment: @MichaelWelch I got my code working.. thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Michael Welch.. I got my code working.. I will post this here..

```
Public Sub SendPostData(ByVal site As String, ByVal message As String)
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    Dim request As WebRequest
    request = WebRequest.Create(site)
    Dim response As WebResponse
    Dim postData As String = "fields " + message
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    request.Method = "POST"

    request.Headers.Add("Client-ID: removed")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer removed")
    request.ContentType = "text/plain"

    request.ContentLength = data.Length

    Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    stream.Close()

    response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    rt.Text = sr.ReadToEnd

End Sub

SendPostData("https://api.igdb.com/v4/games/", "name, url; where id = 296;")
```